# Facebook authentication on Rails 5 ,no method [] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-5.1

i want to login to my website using facebook account,first i created file **facebook.yml** in config

```
development:
app_id: 28679*********
secret: ba02f0735cfdd4************
```

Then i created **facebook.rb** in /config/initializers

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

Next ,i make another file called **omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret'], {:scope => 'public_profile, email'},{:info_fields => 'id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,email,name,link'}
end
```

Now,if i run anything it keeps saying that

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/home/van/FastMail/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/omniauth-1.7.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:6:in `initialize'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `new'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:35:in `build'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `block in build'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `each'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `inject'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:99:in `build'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:508:in `block in app'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `synchronize'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:504:in `app'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:45:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/home/van/FastMail/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/van/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Although u can see that i created method [] in facebook.rb, I don't know what wrong

Answer (score 0):

ok ,i found out one way ,just delete FACEBOOK_CONFIG in omniauth file and input the app_id and secret directly.